# Does uniform convergence on compacts of drifts in rough differential equation imply convergence of solutions?

Tags: differential-equations, rough-paths

Consider the RDE

$$dY^n=b_n(Y^n) \, dt+\sigma(Y^n) \, d\mathbf X$$

where $\mathbf X$ is a rough path, $\sigma$ is as smooth as you'd like and $b_n$ are Lipschitz. If $b_n\to b$ uniformly then Friz-Victoir theorem 12.11 gives that $Y^n\to Y$ in sup norm. What if $b_n\to b$ uniformly on compacts, does the same hold?